# Can not find the Field name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

```
strSQL = " SELECT W.wrhID, " & _
         " W.wrhName AS WName " & _
         " FROM tblWarehouse AS W " & _
         " WHERE W.wrhID IN ( " & Forms.frmStockControl.Form.txtwrhIDs & " )"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
 Do Until rst.EOF
    Dim strlbl$, strlblV$
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.count
        strlbl = "Me.lblWarehouse" & i
        strlblV = "Me.lblWarehouse" & i
        Me.Controls(strlbl).Caption = rst!WName
        Me.Controls(strlblV).visible = True
    Next
    rst.MoveNext
 Loop
```

I am getting error msg `2465 - Can not find the Field name`

but field Name exists in my form.
Pls help.

Comment: Which line is debug highlighting? I think you should refer to `txtwrhIDs` differently; perhaps using this convention: `Forms!Mainform!ControlName` I also don't think you can get to the caption or visibility properties through `Me.Controls(Me.myControl)` method.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to addres a form control in VBA is either:

```
Forms![YourFormName]![YourControlName]
```

The brackets are only required if the name contains blanks.

or

```
Forms("YourFormName").Controls("YourControlName")
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed

```
strlbl = "Me.lblWarehouse" & i
strlblV = "Me.lblWarehouse" & i
```

to :

```
strlbl = "lblWarehouse" & i
strlblV = "lblWarehouse" & i
```

and is working fine